# iPad Mini and WiFi Connection

Tags: ipad, wifi, ios

I have an iPad Mini (64gb wifi only model running iOS 6) and it will periodically drop the WiFi connection and will take some time to reconnect. My other devices (laptop and iPhone 4 [iOS5]) do not seem to suffer from this issue. (I wonder if the iPhone does have this issue, however, when wifi drops the cellular data kicks in and I do not notice the drop). I am left to wonder why this is happening and what I can do about this issue?

My router is an Actiontec C1000A (ISP is Century Link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With iOS6, the WiFi will drop when the iPad is put to sleep (via power button or closing the smart cover).  When you wake it up, it should automatically reconnect to the WiFi.  However depending on the WiFi environment (many WiFi networks to choose from, a slow/overloaded WiFi router, etc), this could take a few seconds.

If it isn't automatically reconnecting, go into the Settings>WiFi screen and choose your WiFi network.  If it is already checked, click the > on the right and choose to forget that network.  Then you can go back and set it again.